# Defining request and response objects for webapp2 handlers on GAE python

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I already have a REST API with GAE python built using webapp2. I was looking at protorpc messages used in protorpc and Cloud Enpoints and really like how I can define the request and responses. Is there a way to incorporate that into my webapp2 handlers?

Comment: Yes there is, I'm using protorpc with webapp2 currently (not Endpoints as that did not suit my needs). I takes a bit of effort; I have a decorator on the webapp2 method that converts (using the protorpc 'decode_message' methods for POST and GET parameters) from webapp2 request to the protorpc message. I will try to compose a decent answer to get you moving in the right direction when I have a bit of time.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisC73. I'll keep watch of your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly I use a decorator on the webapp2 method. I define the decorator as follows*:

```
    # Takes webapp2 request (self.request on baseHandler) and converts to defined protoRpc object 
    def jsonMethod(requestType, responseType, http_method='GET'):
            """
            NB: if both URL and POST parameters are used, do not use 'required=True' values in the protorpc Message definition 
                    as this will fail on one of the sets of parms
            """
            def jsonMethodHandler(handler):
                    def jsonMethodInner(self, **kwargs):            
                            requestObject = getJsonRequestObject(self, requestType, http_method, kwargs)

                            logging.info(u'request={0}'.format(requestObject))
                            response = handler(self, requestObject) # Response object       
                            if response:
                                # Convert response to Json
                                responseJson = protojson.encode_message(response)
                            else:
                                responseJson = '{}'
                            logging.info(u'response json={0}'.format(responseJson))
                            if self.response.headers:
                                    self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
                            if responseJson:
                                    self.response.write(responseJson)
                                    self.response.write('')

                    return jsonMethodInner
            return jsonMethodHandler
```

The jsonMethod decorator uses a protorpc message for 'requestType' and 'responseType'.
I have constrained the http_method to be either GET, POST or DELETE for a method; you may wish to change this.
Note that this decorator must be applied to instance methods on a webapp2.RequestHandler class (see the example below) as it needs to access the webapp2 request and response objects.

The protorpc message is populated in getJsonRequestObject():

```
    def getJsonRequestObject(self, requestType, http_method, kwargs):
        "kwargs: URL keywords eg: /api/test/<key:\d+> => key"
        "request.GET: used for 'GET' URL query string arguments"
        "request.body: used for 'POST' or 'DELETE' form fields"
        logging.info(u'URL parameters: {0}'.format(kwargs))
        if http_method == 'POST' or http_method == 'DELETE':
            requestJson = self.request.body
            if requestJson == None:
                requestJson = '' # Cater for no body (eg: IE10)
            try:
                logging.info("Content type = {}".format(self.request.content_type))
                logRequest = requestJson if len(requestJson) < 1024 else requestJson[0:1024]
                try:
                    logging.info(u'Request JSON: {0}'.format(logRequest))
                except:
                    logging.info("Cannot log request JSON (invalid character?)")
                postRequestObject = protojson.decode_message(requestType, requestJson)
            except:
                logError()
                raise
            if self.request.query_string:
                # combine POST and GET parameters [GET query string overrides POST field]
                getRequestObject = protourlencode.decode_message(requestType, self.request.query_string)
                requestObject = combineRequestObjects(requestType, getRequestObject, postRequestObject)
            else:
                requestObject = postRequestObject

        elif http_method == 'GET':
            logging.info(u'Query strings: {0}'.format(self.request.query_string))
            requestObject = protourlencode.decode_message(requestType, self.request.query_string)
            logging.info(u'Request object: {0}'.format(requestObject))
        else:
            raise ValidationException(u'Invalid HTTP method: {0}'.format(http_method))
        if len(kwargs) > 0:      
            #Combine URL keywords (kwargs) with requestObject
            queryString = urllib.urlencode(kwargs)
            keywordRequestObject = protourlencode.decode_message(requestType, queryString)
            requestObject = combineRequestObjects(requestType, requestObject, keywordRequestObject)    

        return requestObject
```

getJsonRequestObject() handles GET, POST and webapp2 URL arguments (note: these are entered as kwargs).

combineRequestObjects() combines two objects of the requestType message:

```
    def combineRequestObjects(requestType, request1, request2):
        """
        Combines two objects of requestType; Note that request2 values will override request1 values if duplicated
        """
        members = inspect.getmembers(requestType, lambda a:not(inspect.isroutine(a)))
        members = [m for m in members if not m[0].startswith('_')]
        for key, value in members:
                val = getattr(request2, key)
                if val:
                        setattr(request1, key, val)  
        return request1
```

Finally, a decorated webapp2 method example:

```
    from protorpc import messages, message_types

    class FileSearchRequest(messages.Message):
        """
        A combination of file metadata and file information
        """
        filename = messages.StringField(1)
        startDateTime = message_types.DateTimeField(2)
        endDateTime = message_types.DateTimeField(3)

    class ListResponse(messages.Message):
        """
        List of strings response
        """
        items = messages.StringField(1, repeated=True)  

    ...

    class FileHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):   
        @jsonMethod(FileSearchRequest, ListResponse, http_method='POST')  
        def searchFiles(self, request):
            # Can now use request.filename etc
            ...
            return ListResponse(items=items)
```

Hopefully this will give you some idea of how to go about implementing your own webapp2/protorpc framework.

You can also check and see how Cloud Endpoints is implementing their protorpc message handling. You may also need to dive into the protorpc code itself.

- Please note that I have attempted to simplify my existing implementation, so you may come across various issues that you will need to address in your implementation. 
  In addition methods like 'logError()' and classes like 'ValidationException' are non-standard, so you will need to replace them as you see fit.
  You may also wish to remove the logging at some point.